# Eureka Form: Take an input then format to AttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, eureka-forms

I am trying to format input, using attributedStrings, in a Eureka form to given feedback to the user.  In application the user would enter text, the text would change to attributed text.  (Different formats will be used to show different requirements, etc.) Then seeing the text, the user can correct if needed.

Here is the code I have tried (note, in this example only one attribute is used for simplicity) :

```
 <<< TextAreaRow() {

            $0.tag = "directions"
            $0.placeholder = "Enter Directions here"
            $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 110)
            }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
                cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

            }).cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
                cell.textView.attributedText  = NSAttributedString(
                    string: row.value ?? "",
                attributes: myAttributed)
                cell.update()
            }
```

The code seems to run.  But the text is not formatted.

Comment: Moving the following:  

cell.textView.attributedText  = NSAttributedString(
                    string: row.value ?? "",
                attributes: myAttributed)

to the .cellSetup allows some font attributes to change ie bold/italic etc. but not the full attributed.  Font color does not change.